# RDS Catch-22: Can't add space to out of space volume BECAUSE it's out of space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

RDS informs me my volume is full. But I cannot increase the volume size becuase (drumroll)........ the volume is full.

How do you get out of this catch-22? clicking that orange button just repeats the same message...

[image]

and if is someone is trying to play with your mind...... you cannot stop, or restart this database... only delete it...

Great going AWS.

[image]

Comment: I recall hearing something about "delete the logs" to regain more disk space to get things working. Sorry, can't remember anything more. If you can't resolve it, contact AWS Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and it does seem like an AWS/RDS web interface admin bug:

It seems that whenever you click `Modify` the form gets pre-populated with a `New Master Password`. At this point, any attempt to make a single update -- in my case increasing the volume size will fail with the `"you can't update the volume size while the volume is full, we suggest you increase the volume size"` catch-22 error.

When I manually remove the `New Master Password` value, AWS agreed to update my DB and the volume increase process worked as expected.

Go figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are also pending changes for instance type and publicly-accessible.

You need to fix *only* the space issue, first.  Then make the other changes after you have more space.

Comment: The "Summary of Modifications" needs to show *only* the space change.

Comment: Again- I did that too, after posting this issue. Same response.

Comment: I've got nothing, then -- I've been in this situation more than once, but never encountered this error when only adding storage.